# redirect log outputs to another terminal

Tags: java, linux, shell, io-redirection, gnome-terminal

I have the following script file, which executes a Java main class and print some log data on the terminal. I want to redirect whatever prints this program to another terminal (for example /dev/pts/1, but that didn't work for me). How to do it ?

```
#!/bin/sh

# Usage: ./zipfs_mount.sh file.zip /mount/point

. ./build.conf

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./jni:$FUSE_HOME/lib $JDK_HOME/bin/java \
   -classpath ./build:./lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar \
   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=fuse.logging.FuseLog \
   -Dfuse.logging.level=DEBUG \
   Main -f -s $2 $1 > /dev/pts/1
```

Comment: I'd advise that if it is possible, change the Java program to use a proper logging framework. Logging to stderr is bad practice... If it is not possible, well, you could redirect the output to a file and `tail -F` that... Though you'd have to implement a mechanism to purge the file from time to time to make a limit on the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written should work, assuming that the program writes its log to stdout rather than stderr and that `/dev/pts/1` is the correct device for the other terminal. You can test this with something like:

```
echo Hello > /dev/pts/1
```

This should make `Hello` appear in the other terminal window. If it doesn't, check which device the terminal is using with the `tty` command.

If your program logs to stderr, you can redirect it too:

```
program >/dev/pts/1 2>&1     # send stderr to the same place as stdout
```